# Ambiguous use of 'appendingPathComponent' error

Tags: swift, swift3

I am baffled as to what I should be using in Swift 3 for the following code:

```swift
func fileExist(_ filePath:AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let PdfPathWithFileName = filePath.appendingPathComponent(fileName as String)
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    return fileManager.fileExists(atPath: PdfPathWithFileName)
}
```

I have tried changing the `AnyObject` to `String` but then I get another error:

> 'appendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use appendingPathComponent on URL instead

Any ideas?

Comment: and have you tried `URL` instead of `String` and `AnyObject`?

Comment: I would prefer not to use URL for various reasons

Comment: What is the benefit of using `AnyObject` (which is `Any` in Swift 3 by the way) although the path is required to be `String`? Don't fight the strong type system. I would take the suggestion of the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

`String` now exposes a method `appendingPathComponent(_:)`. You no longer have to cast your `String` to an `NSString`. The answer below is no longer correct (And may have been out-of-date when I posted it.)

---

The method `appendingPathComponent` is a method of NSString. You need to make your parameter an `NSString` if you want to pass in a string. Otherwise pass in an `NSURL`

Comment: thanks I was under the impression that it was String.